# Unable to update user object with class based view 'UpdateView' on user object

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following configuration below for 'UpdateView'.

The form renders fine, with the first and last name I have entered in the backend.

However, if I try update the data and resubmit the form it simply returns as before and the model remains unchanged.

There seems to be a lot of examples of how to do this and they're all quite different.  Would anyone mind telling what i'm doing wrong or be able to point me in the right direction please? This is my first attempt with class views outside of TemplateView so it's still a bit confusing..

```
#urls.py
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),

#views.py
class UserProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = MyUser
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user_profile')

#forms.py
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1}), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'bio']
```

Comment: I take it that `MyUser` has the fields `first_name`, `last_name` and `bio`? Can you post your template and any custom behaviour (e.g. custom save method) on your user model?

Comment: Ok the error was in the template, form not submitting properly.  Thanks a lot!